# Unable to log in using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to **scrape** [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science/supplement/RrrDR/additional-material-and-links) website using python's `BeautifulSoup` package and for automating the user flow I am using selenium. As this website requires authentication to access this page, I am trying to log in first using selenium webdriver. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def configure_driver():
    # Add additional Options to the webdriver
    chrome_options = Options()
    # add the argument and make the browser Headless.
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    # Instantiate the Webdriver: Mention the executable path of the webdriver you have downloaded
    # For linux/Mac
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
    # For windows
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/<user_name>/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver",
        options = chrome_options)
    return driver


def getLinks(driver):
    # Step 1: Go to pluralsight.com, category section with selected search keyword
    driver.get(f"https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science/supplement/RrrDR/additional-material-and-links")
    # wait for the element to load
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_class_name("_ojjigd").is_displayed())
    except TimeoutException:
        print("TimeoutException: Element not found")
        return None
    email = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    print(str(email))
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    email.send_keys("username") # provide some actual username
    password.send_keys("password") # provide some actual password
    form = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
    print(form.submit())
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    print(driver.title)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    # Step 3: Iterate over the search result and fetch the course
    divs = soup.findAll('div', args={'class': 'item-box-content'})
    print(len(divs))

# create the driver object.
driver = configure_driver()
getLinks(driver)
# close the driver.
driver.close()
```

Now after doing `form.submit()` it is expected to log in and change the page, right? But it is simply staying in the same page, so I cannot access the contents of the authenticated page. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no name attribute.

instead of this :

```
form = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
```

Use this :

```
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).click()
```

I tried this code on my local, seems to be working fine

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science/supplement/RrrDR/additional-material-and-links")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys("some user name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("some user name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).click()
```

Since `login` `button` is in a form so `.submit()` should work too.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).submit()
```

This works too.